# tlbimp: how does early binding work with "/noclassmembers"?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, com, interop, tlbimp

I was playing about with [tlbimp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and I found the `/noclassmembers` option and I was like:

> Ahhah! I bet that will break early binding!

But, much to my chagrin, everything still seemed to work fine even when using the interop assembly generated with this option. That is, there were no compilation issues (or apparent run-time issues on *my test machine*) when substituting in this new interop assembly.

So, **what *exactly* does `/noclassmembers` do, and why would it *not* be desirable to *always* use this option?**

Consider the following:

1. Apparently it is sometimes required to "avoid a TypeLoadError exception", and
2. The resulting interop assembly is smaller (it is only 3/4th the size in my case)

(Judging from the file sizes, the Visual Studio automatically generated interop assembly does not use this option.)

Thanks.

Comment: If you wish to understand what are the differences between an assembly generated with or without the option, why don't you run the assemblies through a disassembler and/or .NET Reflector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM uses an interface based programming model.  A coclass itself should not expose any members, it implements interfaces and exposes them with IUnknown::QueryInterface().  A type library does however not prevent a coclass from exposing its own members.  Notable to happen with managed classes that are [ComVisible] and don't apply the [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] attribute.  Those visible implementation details can be the source of the TypeLoadException.

So it is unsurprising that it doesn't cause any problems when you use the option, well-behaved client code will only use the exposed interfaces.  You can use the oleview.exe SDK tool to take a look at the type library and see what is being exposed.  Use File + View Typelib and pick the .tlb or .dll

Comment: "its own members" meaning "members that are not part of a COM interface"?

Comment: Yes, a type library is the equivalent of .NET metadata.  It has features that are not often used in COM.  Like a module exposing static functions.  Or a class exposing its own members.  You can turn that off with /noclassmembers, doesn't make a difference when the COM coclass only exposes interface and no class members.  The normal way.